# GDI+ error when taking screenshot

Tags: c#

When I run the code below to take screenshot, I get an error like `A generic error occurred in GDI+.` How can I resolve this issue or any other way to take screenshot of current window?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 200);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as System.Drawing.Image);

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

    bitmap.Save("c:\\screenshot.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

}
```

Comment: Windows GDI code in a "Page_Load" event? Can you add a few environmental notes please? i.e. in what environment is that code running? If you are trying to get a screenshot in ASP.NET, it won't (as in shouldn't) work since you'd be capturing the server's screen and that would be a heavy security problem... also the server process usually doesn't have a desktop to capture from.

Comment: That only works once, the next time it will bomb on the lock on the file.  Using the *using* statement so the bitmap object gets automatically disposed is never really optional.  And when you pick a clumsy storage location like C:\ then it will never work, only elevated processes can write to that directory.  Use Environment.GetFolderPath so you'll store to AppData or Pictures or Documents.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
bitmap.Save(@"c:\\screenshot.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Also why you define bitmap again, it's not needed:

```
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
```

Comment: thanks now i can took screenshot and may i know in case of scrollbar appears on that screen means if it's possible to take entire page with multiple image screenshot file.

Comment: you want to split every image in the screen on a seperate image file?

Comment: consider to accept or/and upvote an answer if it was helpful

Comment: Yes I want to split every image in the screen and save it.

Comment: it's not an easy tast, you need a function that will identify the images width and height and then to crop it. and maybe it will not be 100% correct all the time. i don't know anything similar available. I know a library that will crop  non rectangular images, i don't know iif it will help you but here it is:  http://www.imagingshop.com/automatic-cropping-of-non-rectangular-images/